# Splice Object from Array - undefined error

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, splice

Within the code below contains a very simple question game (work-in-progress). So far, I've been able to have a "Rules" message appear through the onLoad function, "qDisplayLoad()". Next, the onClick function "qDisplayClick" runs anytime someone clicks, thus randomly pulling from the array (qArray).

My question: 
How do you remove (splice) the question chosen from the array once it has been shown? My goal is to not have the same question repeat twice. Within the code below, you will find my amateur attempt at "splice" (and it kind of works), but instead, the array pushes out "undefined".

```html
var qLoad = 0;
var qArray = [
    "Question 1",
    "Question 2",
    "Question 3",
    "Question 4",
    "Question 5"
];


var randomElement;

/* The text "Rules" appears when the page loads */
function qDisplayLoad() {

    if (qLoad == 0) {
        randomElement = "Rules";
        qLoad = 1; /* Changes qLoad to "1" from "0" so the array begins within the "qDisplayClick" function */
    }

    document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = randomElement;
}

/* A new question is pulled from the array everytime the mouse is clicked (up to a maximum of 5) */
function qDisplayClick() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * qArray.length); /* Questions are randomly chosen and rounded down from the array */

    if (qLoad += 1 && !(qLoad == 7)) {
        qArray.splice(qArray,1);
        randomElement = qArray[randomNumber];

    } else if (qLoad == 0) {
        randomElement = "Rules";
    }
    if (qLoad == 7) { /* After the 5th question, text will appear for the pop up */
        randomElement = "WIP - POP UP PLACEHOLDER";
    }

    document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = randomElement;
}
```

Comment: I found this useful tutorial, but for my code if stills says "undefined".
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_remove

Comment: Why do you mean by the array pushes out undefined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error comes from this line         `qArray.splice(qArray,1);`
The splice method can't take an array as the first parameter:

```
array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX)
```

- index    Required.
- howmany  Optional.
- item1, ..., itemX    Optional. The new item(s) to be added to the array

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, Melchia.

Yes, you are correct! I was able to resolve this issue by updating the following:

```html
randomElement = qArray[randomNumber];
qArray.splice(randomNumber,1);
```

Thank you, and happy new year!